# Date order by with WHERE clause in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to retrieve all the records in ascending order with a WHERE clause. But where to include the WHERE condition in my query? It is working fine for ascending order.

Here is my code. First I am working on this query but here I am not able to implement the ORDER BY clause.

```
Cursor tripdaycursor = sdb.rawQuery(
  "select TripDay_Id, Tripday_Date, Tripday_ParsingDate,
  Trip_Complete, TripDay_Endkm, TripDay_Count, Tripday_EndPlace
  FROM TripDay WHERE Trip_Id="+record, null);
```

So I tried the code below for ascending order:

```
String recordid=Integer.toString(record), Trip_Id="Trip_Id", TripDay_Id="TripDay_Id",
  Tripday_Date="Tripday_Date", Tripday_ParsingDate="Tripday_ParsingDate",
  Trip_Complete="Trip_Complete", TripDay_Endkm="TripDay_Endkm",
  TripDay_Count="TripDay_Count", Tripday_EndPlace="Tripday_EndPlace",
  TripDay = "TripDay";
Cursor tripdaycursor = sdb.query(TripDay, new String[] {
  TripDay_Id, Tripday_Date, Tripday_ParsingDate, Trip_Complete, TripDay_Endkm,
  TripDay_Count, Tripday_EndPlace}, null, null, null, null,
  Tripday_ParsingDate + " ASC");
```

But I want both conditions on a single query, with the WHERE clause and in ascending order. How to do that?

Comment: Can't u use `orderby` with `where` clause?

Comment: how to do that,will u suggest

Comment: Wade Pedersen has answered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put "order by Column_Name" in your query after the where clause. Something like this, with the column you want to order by in ascending order

```
Cursor tripdaycursor = sdb.rawQuery("select TripDay_Id,Tripday_Date,Tripday_ParsingDate,Trip_Complete,TripDay_Endkm,TripDay_Count,Tripday_EndPlace from TripDay where Trip_Id="+record + " order by " + columnName,null);
```

Comment: thank you its working,but if i want records in descending order then

Comment: @pitambar, you can use the same query with "order by DESC". E.g. Cursor tripdaycursor = sdb.rawQuery("select TripDay_Id,Tripday_Date,Tripday_ParsingDate,Trip_Complete,TripDay_Endkm,TripDay_Count,Tripday_EndPlace from TripDay where Trip_Id="+record + " order by DESC " + columnName,null);